# Integrating $sin^n(x)$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I tried different methods of integration, but I can not solve this problem.

$$\int \sin^n (x) dx$$

Comment: Have you heard of reduction formulae?

Comment: Can we assume that $n \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: Hm, sadly, the link only explains how to do it for a given $n$ and cannot be easily made to work for any $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$${\displaystyle \sin ^{n}\theta ={\frac {2}{2^{n}}}\sum _{k=0}^{\frac {n-1}{2}}(-1)^{({\frac {n-1}{2}}-k)}{\binom {n}{k}}\sin {{\big (}(n-2k)\theta {\big )}}}\quad {\text{where n is odd}}$$
$${\displaystyle \sin ^{n}\theta ={\frac {1}{2^{n}}}{\binom {n}{\frac {n}{2}}}+{\frac {2}{2^{n}}}\sum _{k=0}^{{\frac {n}{2}}-1}(-1)^{({\frac {n}{2}}-k)}{\binom {n}{k}}\cos {{\big (}(n-2k{\big )}\theta )}}\quad {\text{where n is even}}$$

Comment: One might reasonable request a source for this identity, which can be easily obtained applying the binomial theorem to $$\sin^n(\theta)=\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}\right)^n$$

Comment: but how to integrate it?

Comment: Its integral is rather trivial.

Comment: ok I see. It is more easy than my identity, thanks

Comment: When $n$ is even, how should one interpret the term $(n-1)/2$ in your expression?

Comment: @Dr.MV you can use the other identity ${\displaystyle \sin ^{n}\theta ={\frac {1}{2^{n}}}{\binom {n}{\frac {n}{2}}}+{\frac {2}{2^{n}}}\sum _{k=0}^{{\frac {n}{2}}-1}(-1)^{({\frac {n}{2}}-k)}{\binom {n}{k}}\cos {{\big (}(n-2k{\big )}\theta )}}$