# Is there any trig identity which can be used for $\int \sin^4x$?

Tags: calculus, integration

What is $\int \sin^4x$?

I tried to use the identity $\sin^2x = \frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$, but I'm stuck.

Comment: @GuyFsone That duplicate invites integration by parts, while this question explicitly asks for trig identities to be used.

Comment: @MarkBennet https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2504357/integration-of-int-sinn-x?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968727/integrating-sinnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use that $$\sin(x)^4=\frac{1}{8} (-4 \cos (2 x)+\cos (4 x)+3)$$

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you deduce that formula?

Comment: you can use the right-hand side and deduce $$\sin(x)^4$$

Comment: should i mak it for you?

Comment: we often use such formulas in our mathcircle, at the university

Comment: for example see here http://www.arndt-bruenner.de/mathe/Allgemein/trigsimpl.htm

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Square both sides

and use $$\cos2y=2\cos^2y-1$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use that identity twice, so you get $$\frac14\int (1-\cos(2x))^2 \,dx$$Then expand the brackets and use another similar formula for the $\cos^2$ term.

Answer (score 1):

### Hint:

use
$$\sin^2ax=\left(\frac{1-\cos( 2ax)}{2}\right)$$
$$\cos^2ax=\left(\frac{1+\cos (2ax)}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the substitution above:

$\sin^4 x = (\frac {1-\cos 2x}2)^2 = \frac 14 - \frac 12 \cos 2x + \frac 14\cos^2 2x $

$\cos^2 2x = \frac {1+\cos 4x}{2}$

Or, using a little complex analysis

$\sin x = \frac {e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}\\
\sin^4 x = \left(\frac {e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^4\\
\frac {e^{4ix} - 4e^{3ix}e^{-ix} + 6e^{2ix}e^{-2ix} - 4e^{ix}e^{-3ix} + 4e{-4ix})}{16}\\
\frac {(e^{4ix} + e^{-4ix})- 4(e^{2ix}+2e^{-2ix}) +6}{16}\\
\frac 18 \cos 4x - \frac 12 \cos 2x + \frac {3}{8}$

Answer (score 0):

You can also calculate as follows:

$$\sin^4x=\sin^2x(1-\cos^2 x)=\sin^2x-\frac 14 \sin^2 2x=\frac {1-\cos 2x}2-\frac {1-\cos 4x}8$$where the second step uses $\sin 2x =2\sin x\cos x$ and you use your original identity for each of the $\sin^2$ expressions which result.